# OpenCV : How to Serialise and de-serialise MatND object?

Tags: c++, sqlite, opencv

I need to serialize and de-serialize OpenCV `MatND` objects in C++.
I need to do so in order to be able to save these objects into an `sqlite` database.

I'm writing this in C++.
If you have another approach, I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Did you try OpenCV persistence module? It can write and read matrices from disk: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

Comment: Didn't know that this existed, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to same the serialized object, and you do not save the mat it self? or saving the results in xml for example?
if you need to compare the images then you may save just the histogram for each image in the database, and after that you may compare just the histogram

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

anyway did you try protobuf
https://github.com/google/protobuf

any you may see Serialization using boost
https://cheind.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/serialization-of-cvmat-objects-using-boost/

Comment: How do I save the 'mat itself' ? 
I need a fast way to compare 800 images.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to do, I have my histogram in a `MatND` (like the example) I need to save that into my DB

Comment: I think there is no direct way to do this, you have to either store the histogram in files and read from files (or xml), or store each value of the histogram in the database.

Comment: Neither will give me the speed I need to treat 800 pictures per request. 
If I do this I think it will be equivalent to the 20 seconds it takes to go through the pictures.